# Is Fluoride really that good for tooth enamel?

Tags: teeth

Recently, I started to pay more attention to my teeth because of the high number of tooth decays, and I'm trying to understand different concepts and biological functions of the teeth and bone. By searching around, I have found that enamel is the strongest bio-material in our body and that it is the main player in tooth decay. So I started searching for methods to restore the enamel, and I can see that most of the dentists recommend using Fluoride-based toothpaste. At the same time, the literature tells us that Fluoride is quite toxic. So I looked for healthy options available for end-users, and the organic toothpaste that I found are all without Flouride.

Now my questions are:

- Should I go for an organic Toothpaste without Flouride or a non-organic with Flouride for restoring the enamel?
- Is Flouride really the only enamel restorer?
- Can it be replaced with something else for the restoration?

I'm a mechanical engineer and I can understand technical language, therefore any type of technical explanation would be great (even with chemical reactions)

Comment: "At the same time, the literature tells us that Fluoride is quite toxic." Does it tell you the doses it's toxic at ? How much toothpaste are you planning on eating ?

Comment: Here is a [reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2908039/) where you might find some information. And here [another one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3698581/) dealing with an *in vitro* comparison of the effect of organic and inorganic fluoride on enamel.

Comment: this paper answers your second and third question :http://www.jisppd.com/article.asp?issn=0970-4388;year=2012;volume=30;issue=1;spage=2;epage=6;aulast=Goswami

Comment: Getting fluoride in drinking water is more effective, since its concentration in water depends on the temperature , it may lead to overdose and may cause mottled teeth.

Comment: Thank you guys for the links! I will start reading it. Not sure how to interpret your last comment JM97. Edit: I'm not trying to kill myself :-) At least not yet.

Comment: This question appears to be framed in more of a "personal health question" vs asking strictly about the biology/biochemistry involved in the fluoride-enamel "strengthening"  process. As a result, I think this question will be voted to be closed as being off topic. However, even with additional edits, I'd say you'd find your answer through a quick google search.